# How could I select each group within an IGrouping with Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I am trying to select from an `IQueryable` ome fields then from an `IGrouping` the amount on each of them. but apparently it doesn't seem to work the query looks like

```cs
var selectGrouping = 
"new (it.Key as Key 
, it.Select(it.CentroId).Distinct().Count() as CantidadCentros
, it.Select(it.OfertaFomativaId).Distinct().Count() as Acciones
, new (it.First().AccionFormativaId as AccionFormativaId
     , it.First().EstadoId as EstadoId
     , it.First().OfertaFormativaNombre as OfertaFormativaNombre
     , it.First().AmbitoNombre as AmbitoNombre
     , it.First().CantidadAcciones as CantidadAcciones
     , it.First().CentroId as CentroId) as Value)"

var select =
"new (AccionFormativaId
, EstadoId
, OfertaFormativa.Nombre as OfertaFormativaNombre
, Ambito.Nombre as AmbitoNombre
, OfertaFormativa.AccionFormativa.Count as CantidadAcciones
, CentroId)"
```

and the Linq query

```cs
var re = queryable
             .Select(select)
             .GroupBy(fields, "it")
             .Select(selecGrouping)
             .ToDynamicList();
```

this only returns the first of the items in the group but not each of them... how can I select of them in the `IGrouping`?

Comment: Please try to reformat your post with [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code blocks (that will compile).  Right now, it's difficult to understand what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't see how Dynamic Linq is of any use here, is there a reason you can't go back to `Expression<>`-based Linq?

Comment: @Dai the front end request which table to query from that´s why

Comment: @PontiacGTX That sounds like a gaping security hole....

Comment: @Dai well it could be solved with resitricting which tables could query but at the end they couldnt even use this service properly